# Is Man-In-The-Middle necessary for a CA to read HTTP plaintext?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, x.509, trust

Although I understand the basic theory behind certificates and asymmetric cryptography, I'm not quite sure on the details of the X.509 protocol. I'm wondering what attacker model a given CA requires to attack the TLS/SSL traffic. Specifically, if I assume my CA to leak the private key it issued me to a third party Mallory (Mallory might also be identical to CA), can **passive eavesdropping** of TCP packets enable Mallory to get the plaintext? Or does Mallory need Man-In-The-Middle capabilities to read the plaintext?

My rationale for this is as follows: if the certifiacte merely enables a verified Diffie-Hellman, you have to interfere with the key exchange to be able to fool server and client into using your own key(s). But does X.509 do so?

Answer (score 15):

CA does not issue private keys to anybody. CA *signs* (using its own private key, which is kept *very* secret) your *public* key. The CA has no access to your private key at all.

If the CA’s private key is leaked to Mallory, Mallory is able to issue valid certificates for any name. That means he can make almost undetectable (well, obviously, you *can* detect the certificate changed, but how many users check that?) man-in-the-middle attacks. But he has nothing which would help him with passive eavesdropping.

If *your* private key is leaked, passive eavesdropping might be possible, but in that scenario, the CA takes no part at all.

Comment: While all your points are interesting, I was primarily interested in what happens if my private key leaks (but I was biased against a CA **who actually issues the private key**, so I made the question more convoluted as it had to be). So, there is no session key exchange and the private key *does* give everybody who obtains it the ability to eavesdrop?

Comment: It depends. If you use a [PFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) ciphersuite, you cannot decrypt the communication just by eavesdropping, even if you know the server private key. But when using RSA key exchange, you can, see e.g. [this Wireshark guide to do that](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).

Comment: These are good points, but the last statement is a bit misleading, as passive eavesdropping is never possible without being in the middle of the SSL handshake.

Comment: @AaronLS That isn't true for RSA key exchanges.

Comment: @Xander I didn't say it was. I specifically said SSL, but you fail to make the distinction between SSL traffic which the OP mentioned in his question.  He is making an overly generalized statement IMO to say passive eavesdropping might be possible.  "for certain key exchange protocols" would be better wording to emphasize it depends, because for some it is not "sometimes" but "never".

Comment: @AaronLS SSL has RSA key exchanges as well; in fact, I'd bet that very, very, very few SSL implementations use DHE, and that almost all of them use RSA key exchange.

Comment: @cpast You are right. I have read a lot on SSL and never heard of other key exchange algorithms being used.  I assumed everyone played by the same rules for interoperability. I assumed Xander was referring to cipher suites used in other non-SSL encryption protocols. My apologies.

Comment: @cpast ECDHE, and less so DHE (often only 1024-bit), are widely supported nowadays.

Comment: @MattNordhoff But that's generally on sites using TLS, not SSL.